# App Engine Java - Extract thumbnail from mp4 video

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have some video stored on Google Cloud Storage in mp4, i need the extract a thumbnail from them.

I looked to a number of solutions, and looks like they don't work with App Engine.

for example: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

Do you have library that i could use to do this on Google App Engine in Java?

Comment: I don't think you'll find some pure java solution for this

Comment: Yes i don't mind using libraries, the trick is to find one working with App Engine :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally went with Google Compute Engine and ffmpeg, implementation is in progress...

Answer (score 0):

This question looks related to [Is there a Java API for mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015393/is-there-a-java-api-for-mp4-files)

Xuggler says their project is a mix of java and native code. Native code will not run on java app engine.

Search for `java mp4 video decoder` and look for a decoders that only use java code. Perhaps this one will work: http://jcodec.org/guide/movstitch.html.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some searching, I've found following: [Video website on google application engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616934/video-website-on-google-application-engine)

Sounds like similar problem to yours. The only difference is that the other thread checks for python solution. However answers seem to be quite programming language independent, so I think it will be worth a read.

For the documentation/inspirational purposes, it might be worth to describe your solution in this thread once you go for it.

Comment: I already this post before, but the solution is ... to not use App Engine to do it, so it's not what i'm looking for, but thank you ;)